# abstract method "void com.squareup.picasso.Callback.onError(java.lang.Exception)

Tags: android, callback, adapter, picasso, onerror

I'm new Devoloper, I want to load image from FirebaseDatabase with Picasso. But I'm getting this error ;

abstract method "void com.squareup.picasso.Callback.onError(java.lang.Exception)

I dont understand what it means. Because I'm using already Callback method. Here is my adapter ;

```
 private void myAdapter() {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference().child("Category");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>().setQuery(query, Category.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false);
                return new MenuViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Category model) {
                viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso p = Picasso.get();
                p.load(model.image).tag(this).into(viewHolder.menu_image, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.getMessage();
                    }
                });


                final Category clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, "" + clickItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent food_intent = new Intent(Home.this, FoodList.class);
                        //Because categoryId is key , so we just get key of this item
                        food_intent.putExtra(getCategoryId, adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        food_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(food_intent);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
      adapter.startListening();
    }
```

I have googled from internet but I couldn't find anything useful to do. Please help me and thank you :)

this is my model class ;

```
public class Category {

    private String name;
    public String image;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String name, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

this is my [FirebaseDatabase constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDNFz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback is working fine, but the image couldn't be loaded. Could you tell us more about "model.image". Try replacing it with a hardcoded URL, you are sure of that it works.

Comment: I think so, its working fine. I have model that it includes image URL and name. I'm loading from FirebaseDatabase. I have been working for 1 month for this project. Until last 3 days I have faced this problem. Normally It was working fine. I will edit question about model class and after doing check it again pls

Comment: added sir please check it

Comment: Have you checked manually if the URLs are still valid in a browser? If not please do so.
Or have you updated the version of Picasso recently? Then you may want to change it back, because as you can see here one of the recent versions of Picasso seems to cause this error  on some devices. https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1928

Comment: sir Updated all of url but getting same error :( using last version of Picasso. get() is not used for previous versions.  I have checked link you mentioned but ı have seen before. Let me tell you what's happening while app is running. Firstly all images comes and as you can see onSucces method I can get Toast Message. "Welcome". after a few seconds running onError method and getting toast message again and "Failed!". And app crashes out!

Comment: As the problem described in the link is on latest version, I recommend trying an older one.
The callback can only be success or error, not both. Since you are using an adapter, I guess some of the images can't be loaded, ie. some URLs must be invalid or null.
Other from these two I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: thanks for interest, there is no problem with url. I have tried manually all of them. I know that The callback can only be success or error, not both. because I wanted to see whats happening , I have add toast Message and I can see both of them. I will an older version as you say, if it works I will comment.

Comment: thanks a lot your interest my dear, older version is worked for me. I have tried 2.5.2 version of picasso and it is working fine. But we need to focus on why it happens. .

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

Try like this,

```
Picasso.with(this).load(model.image).resize(400,400).into(viewHolder.menu_image, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
               // onError Load Default Image.
            }
        });
```